# Does iterating a certain function related to the sums of divisors eventually always result in a prime value?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, prime-numbers, divisors-multiples

Let define the following function for integers (from 2): $f(x)=\sigma(x)-1$, where $\sigma$ is the sum of the divisors of $x$.
For example $f(6)=6+3+2=11$, $f(5)=5$.
Note that $x$ is a fixed point for $f$ if and only if, $x$ is prime.

If we iterate starting at any integer $x$ we get a dynamical system.

Computations with Maple showed that for all integer $x$ in $[2,2000000]$ there exists an integer $n$ such that $(f \circ f \circ \dots \circ f)(x)$ is prime; that is for each integer $x$ the sequence generated is stationary.
The question is: can anyone help proving the conjecture ?

Thank you for any help on the subject.

Comment: Welcome on MO! Although what you describe seems nice, I fail to see a question here. Could you please be more specific as to what your question might be?

Comment: It looks to me a quite nice ``problem''. I suggest you to add the tags of dynamical systems and ergodic theory.

Comment: The question is to prove that: for every $x\in \mathbb N $ there exists an $n(x)\in \mathbb N$ such that $f^{n(x)}(x)$ is prime.

Comment: I have a question: Are the primes that you got in your experiments uniformly distributed in some sense? Or are there prime numbers that occur more often that others?

Comment: Does the number $n$ of necessary iterations get "arbitrarily large", or do you observe from your experiments that typically very few iterations suffice?

Comment: for n between 2 and 2000000 it seems that it happens quickly less than 50).
I did not looked, neither at the distribution of the "quickest" integers, nor at the primes that are reached; I try to understand the easy integers (such as the product of 2 primes); it is easy to see that the number of divisors is not necessarily decreasing.

Comment: Guy's book on unsolved problems in number theory is a good if old resource for such problems.  Start your literature search there.  Your operator resembles near perfect numbers, perhaps that literature will help.

Comment: See also OEIS sequence A039654: http://oeis.org/A039654

Comment: Also https://oeis.org/A039656 .

Comment: The conjecture is true up to $2 \cdot 10^{8}$. Of the numbers less than that, the one that requires the most steps to reach a prime is $n = 153847984$ (76 steps).

Comment: $n=1271300352$ is the first to take 89 steps, the conjecture is true up to that point, and every other number of steps below 105 appears by then.

Answer (score 19):

$\sigma(n)$ grows not too much faster than $n$: $\sigma(n) = O(n \log \log n)$.
This is slow enough that we should have $\log f^{(n)}(x) = O(n \log n)$ say.
Heuristically, the probability that $f^{(n)}(x)$ is prime should be 
something like $1/\log f^{(n)}(x)$, and since $\sum_n \dfrac{1}{n \log n}$ diverges, we would expect to eventually reach a prime with probability $1$.
Of course, this is not a proof, but it does provide  some justification for believing the conjecture.

Comment: And the fact that values of $\sigma$ tend to be more composite/have smaller prime factors than typical integers means that the values of $f$ are even more likely to be prime.

Comment: Also, $\sigma(n)$ is likely to have many small prime factors, so $f(n)$ is likely not to, which further improves the odds.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer Do you mean to make a point different from the one that  Greg Martin made and if so which, or did you just overlook his comment?

Comment: @quid Just overlooked, sorry. While I'm at it, though, I'll point out that, if $n\equiv 2 \bmod 3$ then $f(n) \equiv 2 \bmod 3$ and, if $n \equiv 3 \bmod 4$ then $f(n) \equiv 3 \bmod 4$. This might be useful.

Comment: Also, unless $n$ is a square or twice a square, $f(n) \equiv 1 \mod 2.$ $f(n) \equiv 0 \mod 3$ seems pretty rare although $f(n) \equiv 0 \mod 5$ seems to happen about $\frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{5}$ of the time.

Answer (score 5):

Every prime occurs at least once (obviously) as the end of a trajectory. However many occur only once and some occur quite often. Since $f$ is non-decreasing it is easy by simple computation to find all $x$ which end up at a particular prime $p$.

Primes such that $p+1$ has many small prime factors are likely to occur often. For example, there are $125$ starting points which end at $5039$ but the nearby primes $5011,5023,5051, 5059$ and $5057$ can be reached only from themselves while $5021$ can be reached starting from itself and one other place, $2650=2\ 5^2\ 53$ with $\sigma(2650)=(2+1)(25+5+1)(53+1)=2\ 3^4\ 31=5022.$ It is not too hard to establish that $\sigma(x)=2651$ has no solutions.

On the other hand, $5040=2^33^25\ 7$ can be factored in may ways as the product of several   factors, which must have only small prime factors. Here are all the ways so that each factor is one less than a prime.

$[3, 4, 14, 30], [3, 6, 14, 20], [3, 4, 420], [3, 12, 140], [3, 20, 84], [4, 14, 90], $$[4, 30, 42], [4, 1260], [6, 14, 60], [6, 20, 42], [12, 14, 30], [6, 840],$$ [14, 18, 20], [12, 420], [14, 360], [20, 252], [30, 168], [60, 84]$

These, with $5039$ itself, give the $19$ square free integers with $\sigma(x)-1=5039.$ There are others which are not square free, such as $x=4y$ for odd $y$ with $\sigma(y)=720$ (also examples coming from $\sigma(3^3)=40$ and from  $\sigma(2^5)=63$.) There are as well starting points which land at $5039$ after several steps.

I'd expect $6719=(2^6\ 3\ 5 \ 7)-1$ to occur quite often, but I haven't checked.

Comment: "*Since f is non-decreasing...*". However $\ f(4)=6 > 5=f(5),\ $ and this is not the only counterexample.

Comment: I simply meant that $x \le f(x)$ so one can quickly compute the set of all $x$ whose trajectory ends at $p.$

Comment: You mean: $\ \forall_{n\ge 2}\,f(n)\ge n.\ $ (You could say so). Thank you.

Comment: According to the table at https://oeis.org/A039654/b039654.txt, there are 168 starting points that reach 6719.

Comment: ... and that is the most for any prime < 10000.  There are 132 that reach $9743 = 2^4\; 3\; 7\; 29 - 1$ and 143 that reach $8783 = 2^4\; 3^2\; 61$.

Comment: I would like to  add that if you change f(n) to sum of divisors +1 and wait for a prime ther are n for which you have to wait much longer and some which "do not reach a prime" ( in a great but fixed number of steps). So the answer would not be probabilistic. On the other side it seems difficult to find useful indications about the divisors of f(n).....

Comment: let me be more precise

Comment: @teller ok, be more precise

Comment: if you take f(n)= sum of divisors+1 and n is a power of 2 you get an infinite sequence of powers of 2; so the probabilistic point of vue is problematic or the point of vue could be " what could be the set of starting points that do not lead to a prime ?" or "what is the set of integers k such that f(n)=k+sum of divisors of n leads always to a prime ?"